# How to implement pagination against mysql in vertx

Tags: pagination, mariadb, vert.x, mariasql

We re returning a resultset from a sql query in form of JsonArray

```
SQLConnection connection = conn.result();
            connection.query(prepareQuery(filters.getString("limit"), filters.getString("since"), filters.getString("end"), filters.getString("filter")), res -> {

             ...
             handler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(arrayJs));
             connection.close();
}); ..
```

But we need to implement pagination in this now.

What is the best way to go with this in Vertx?

Answer (score 3):

Vert.x does not handle pagination: you must handle it in your SQL queries.

There are examples on Stackoverflow for pagination with Oracle, SQLServer, MySQL, Postgres... etc.